# Execution of sequential delete and uncommitted read

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, isolation-level, nolock

We are running the following queries using dynamic SQL, which is erroring out for few cases when we run concurrent instances. The error is:

> *Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement...*

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/could-not-continue-scan-with-nolock-due-to-data-movement) says this error is thrown when a process reads data which is being deleted by another process. Our process is deleting and reading the same rows, however one after the other as per following query (the `SELECT` is after the `DELETE`):

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE colum1 = somevalue1
AND column2 = somevalue2

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE colum1 = somevalue1
AND column2 = somevalue2
```

I am trying to understand the execution of above query. As the `SELECT` is uncommitted, does it start executing before the `DELETE` is committed? Would this mean that removing the `NOLOCK` hint would stop the error?

Comment: The error isn't caused by the `DELETE ... SELECT` from a single session. That always runs sequentially. The issue is the `SELECT (NOLOCK)` running concurrently with data modifications in a different session.

Comment: @MartinSmith So.. `SELECT (NOLOCK)` will not ignore the locks caused by `DELETE` and will begin execution only after `DELETE` is committed ? Then probably error is because of some other query as we are not running more than one  instance of `DELETE ... SELECT` parallely acting on same rows.

Comment: Can you use snapshot isolation instead of NOLOCK?

Comment: @kanu - It will begin executing after the `DELETE` has finished because that's the way TSQL works. It won't fire off an asynch delete then start on the `SELECT` before that statement has finished. Whether it is committed or not depends if both statements are running in the same transaction or not. But either way it is irrelevant. As stated earlier you are getting this because of activity from a different spid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *As the `SELECT` is uncommitted, does it start executing before the `DELETE` is committed?*

No, T-SQL statements always execute sequentially in SQL Server. The point is the `SELECT` may read *uncommitted changes* made by other concurrently-executing transactions.

> *Would this mean that removing `NOLOCK` should stop the error?*

Yes, but only because [error 601](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-601-database-engine-error) is only possible when the [transaction isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) is `READ UNCOMMITTED`. Moving to a different isolation level prevents that particular error from occurring.

#### Additional information

Error 601 can occur for a variety of reasons, but all share a common theme: the SQL Server engine was following some pointer chain or other, when it encountered a situation where a structure it was expecting to be present had been moved or deleted by another concurrently-executing process.

The number of cases where error 601 can occur has been progressively reduced over SQL Server releases, with SQL Server 2012 the least likely to return this error, though it is still possible.

My own view is that all error 601 incidents are bugs - for a suitable value of 'bug'. The behaviour is certainly undesirable, and goes well beyond the SQL standard's description of phenomena that may be encountered under the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level.

While it is certainly true that the SQL standard does not define the detailed behaviours of the different isolation levels [very well](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-95-51.pdf), what it does say leads to the common belief that the *only consequence* of `READ UNCOMMITTED` is that a transaction may see data that has been changed by another transaction before that other transaction commits. As a result of that, using `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level is often justified on the basis that almost all transactions commit very quickly (and very few roll back) so reading 'dirty' data is just a timing difference.

Unfortunately, the implementation of `READ UNCOMMITTED` in SQL Server goes *much further* than simple dirty reads. A `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction in SQL Server can return duplicated data, a partial read of a large data type, skip data records entirely, or simply fail with an 601 error.

It is [possible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/04/25/read-committed-isolation-level/) to experience some of these behaviours under `READ COMMITTED` [and even](https://web.archive.org/web/20170421204904/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/04/10/selects-under-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-may-return-incorrect-results.aspx) `REPEATABLE READ`. This leads some to conclude that the only acceptable isolation levels are those that provide at least statement-level consistency, namely `row-versioning READ COMMITTED`, `SNAPSHOT` isolation, or `SERIALIZABLE`.

Of these, `row-versioning READ COMMITTED` is usually the easiest to transition to. See [this Books Online Topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide) and its subtree for details of row-versioning isolation levels.